Customize populate_obj on Flask AppBuilder view
Is there a way to override the population of an item from a form on edit and/or create on Flask AppBuilder?
On Flask-Admin there is a method called update_model that can be overridden, and I am looking for a behavior like that. So that I can have access to both the item that is being create (the model's instance) and the form with its data.
For the moment I've only found the method pre_add (and its equivalent pre_update) but they don't have access to the form and its data. What would be the leanest way to implement a behavior similar to update_model ?

Try This
from flask_appbuilder import ModelView
from flask_appbuilder.form import DynamicForm

class CustomForm(DynamicForm):
    def on_form_pre_process(self, form, model, **kwargs):
        # Modify the model or form data here
        # form is the form instance
        # model is the model instance being created or updated
        if model:
            # Example: Set a default value or modify a field
            model.some_field = form.some_field.data.upper()

class MyModelView(ModelView):
    form = CustomForm

    def pre_add(self, item):
        # Custom pre-add logic if needed
        pass

    def pre_update(self, item):
        # Custom pre-update logic if needed
        pass


Does that means that I would have to implement the whole form myself (with all the fields, etc) instead of having them being automatically generated by the model?
